# Cumulative Update - best practise

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, cumulative-update

Which is the **best practise to update SharePoint farm**?
Should I stop some services? 
Do I have to check something after the update?

Answer (score 0):

1. Always test your updates on test servers: Installing and testing updates on test server first will minimize risk in production. Perform a thorough regression testing on test server after installing updates and then proceed to production.
2. If you have WFE and Application Server(s) separately configured, then its a good practice to install the updates on Application Server first as it hosts the Central Admin site and then install the updates on WFE server.
3. After successful installation of updates on each server,

   > restart the servers
   >
   > then run your SharePoint Configuration Wizard first in your Application Server(s) and later in your WFE server.
   >
   > In case of failure, please review the error log presented to determine the source and note that you may sometime need to execute the **psconfig** command instead of running SharePoint Configuration Wizard. (Because in some cases SharPoint Configuration Wizard might fail)
4. Open Central Admin Site and go to Upgrade and Migration > Check product and patch installation status and take notice of the new build version. Also, notice that it provides a link to the KB article for details on what was fixed.
5. While still in Central Administration, go to Upgrade and Migration > Check upgrade status to see that the upgrade succeeded.

**To stop any service:** it depends on what version of Cumulative Update you are installing. It's best practice to go through the step-by-step instructions provided by Microsoft on CU website. I have seen some updates require SPTimerV4 and Seach Service service to stop and other updates might need other services to stop. Therefore, the best practice should not be only to download and install the right update but also going the instructions and important points given on the website.